# C printf formatting: What does "." and "|" mean in this context?

Tags: c

I'm taking a security course and am having trouble understanding this code due to a lack of understanding of the C programming language.

```
printf  ("%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x|%s|");
```

I was told that this code should move along the stack until a pointer to a function is found.

I thought the `.` was just an indicator of precision of output, so I don't know what this means in this context since there are indicators of precision?

Also, I don't understand what the `|` means, and I can't find it in the C documentation.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. It just prints a `.` and a `|` respectively.

Comment: So, how does it know to print a . instead of using the special meaning for a .?

Comment: @user1330217 Bothered to read the answer of Neil? "since they are outside of a format specifier"...

Comment: Because by the time it reaches the `.` it knows it has parsed the specifier `%08x` completely, so until it sees another `%` everything is just a literal string to print.

Comment: That's only half of the necessary information for the `printf`.  You have shown us the format string but none of the matching arguments!

Comment: @CarlNorum I think that is the source code.  I think he is learning about [printf vunerabilities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672996/format-string-vulnerability-printf)

Comment: Ah I see - that makes good sense.  I guess we need some ABI information, then!

Comment: "I was told that this code should move along the stack until a pointer to a function is found." Don't believe that. Calling `printf` with that format string (after the "smart" quotes have been fixed) and no further arguments would with my gcc print the contents of four registers (`esi, edx, ecx, r8d`), and whatever `r9` points to as a string, the latter would often crash. To pick arguments from the stack, more conversions would be required (here).

Comment: To be completely accurate, in the context of the format string you're providing  it means " print the character '|' ". (or '.').

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The symbols have no special meaning here since they are outside of a format specifier, they are simply output literally. Note however that you haven't provided all the arguments that printf expects so it will instead print 5 values that happen to be on the stack.

Comment: So why is |%s| necessary at the end? What string would be printed?

Comment: @user1330217 Maybe this is supposed to print an additional string.

Comment: @user1330217 Just like the dots, the pipes mean nothing. They will simply cause a "|" characters to be printed on each side of the string.

Comment: @user1330217, your post didn't contain the variables passed as part of this printf statement, so that's impossible to answer.  If you give us a complete example, Neil can update his answer for you.

Comment: It might print values in registers, too - it's going to be pretty ABI related.

Answer (score 2):

In this string the . and | characters are just outputted.  The dots acted as separators for hex strings and the pipes highlighting a string.

The dots are only considered an indicator of precession if they appear after the % sign and before the format specifier, for example `%4.2f`.

Comment: How does it know to print a . instead of using the precision meaning of a dot?

Comment: @user1330217, because the letter `x` in your example ends the format specifier.  Notice that the `.` comes before the `f` in Steve's example.

Comment: Because the . is not between a % and a g or f. So it is not "special", it's just like any other character that you may want to print with printf - when you do `printf("Hello, World!\n");` H, e, l, l, o etc don't have any special meaning, right?